# Where does the drawing tablet pressure value get mapped to?

Tags: x11, mouse, c++

### Question:

I want to write a simple C++ program which retrieves the current pressure and prints it to the terminal. Where is stylus pressure temporarily saved in memory? Can I request a pointer to it / can I retrieve it via a system utility library function? I can write all the other code.

Edit: can I use/should I use something like system(`/sbin/sysctl -a`)...?

### Background:

I have a Genius Mouse&Pen drawing tablet that seems to use udev somehow (from what I've gather from conversation). It has been natively supported by Ubuntu since 11.04 and prior to that (since ~8.04) I've had it via modifying X11's Config (IIRC). Gnome udev programs work fine (eg. gimp (mostly), mypaint), However KDE-based tablet-aware applications (eg. Krita) have never worked with it, as they only support the Wacom brand in my experience - I only mention this as it might change where the values are saved??.

Comment: Can you use `xidump` from wacom-tools?

Comment: I don't think so, but that is a great start. I will have to look into that.